# Checking for duplicate values in BinarySearchTree

Tags: java

I'm looking to continually look through my BinarySearchTree just in case there are duplicate values for `File f`, instead of ending once the first instance of `File f` is found. I need to return all instances of `File f`.

Right now this is my code for finding the `File`.

```
public File locateHelper(File f, Node<File> node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return null;
    }

    int result = f.compareTo(node.data);
    if (result == 0) {
        return f;
    }
    if (result < 0) {
        return locateHelper(f, node.leftChild);
    }

    return locateHelper(f, node.rightChild);

}
```

I've been trying to switch this to return possibly an `ArrayList<File>` instead of an individual file, but I keep running into `NullPointerException` problems.

How would you guys go about this?

Comment: By what do you plan to search for files, and how to you want to handle the case of multiple matches?  Do you want _all_ files or just the first one?

Comment: I want the ones that are equal to `File f`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would solve it with something like this:

```
public ArrayList<File> collectTree( Node<File> root )
{
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    collectTree( root, files );
    return files;
}

private void collectTree( Node<File> node, ArrayList<File> files )
{
    if( node == null )
        return;
    collectTree( node.leftChild, files );
    files.add( node.data );
    collectTree( node.rightChild, files );
}
```

This will return the contents of the entire tree in an `ArrayList<File>`.

Then, finding duplicates is a simple matter of walking the tree and checking adjacent elements.

You could do it without having to collect the entire tree inside an `ArrayList`, by using the visitor pattern, (look it up,) so instead of collecting nodes in a list you would be invoking some `Consumer<File>` which checks whether the file that it is currently being given is the same as the file that it was given in the last invocation.

**Amendment**

Okay, I am terribly sorry, I thought about it a bit more, (after my answer was upvoted and accepted,) and I came up with a much better solution which only involves searching for the first occurrence and then collecting only the duplicates.

It is based on the observation that once the first matching node is found, then all subsequent matching nodes will be either in the left subtree or in the right subtree of that node, but nowhere else in the entire tree.  So:

1. Do a simple search through the binary search tree to find the first matching node.
2. Recursively collect all matching nodes from each subtree of that node.

Here is how it may look like.  (Please note that I have not tested this, so it may contain little mistakes.)

```
public Collection<File> findAndCollectDuplicates( Node<File> root, File f )
{
    /* find a matching node; if none found, return an empty collection. */
    Node<File> node = findNode( root, f );
    if( node == null )
         return Collections.emptyList();

    /* collect duplicates and return them. */
    List<File> duplicates = new ArrayList<>();
    collectDuplicates( node, f, duplicates );
    return duplicates;
}

private Node<File> findNode( Node<File> root, File f )
{
    for(;;)
    {
        int result = f.compareTo( root.data );
        if (result == 0)
            return root;
        root = result < 0? root.leftChild : root.rightChild;
        if( root == null )
            return null;
    }
}

private void collectDuplicates( Node<File> node, File f, Collection<File> duplicates )
{
    if( node == null )
        return;
    if( f.compareTo( node.data ) != 0 )
        return;
    duplicates.add( node.data );
    collectDuplicates( node.leftChild );
    collectDuplicates( node.rightChild );
}
```

Comment: I apologize for my original post not being clear. I meant that I would like to search and get all instances of `File f`. @MikeNakis

Comment: Right, I understand.  So, the answer is, "use the visitor pattern, Luke!"

Comment: I googled it, it doesn't make much sense to me to be honest. So instead of having 2 methods, this visitable needs me to make a whole new class and implement an interface? @MikeNakis or can I implement `visitable` in my binary search tree and create `visit(File f)` and it will search through the whole tree?

Comment: Yes, that's what it requires, unfortunately.  That's why collecting everything in the `ArrayList` is a highly inefficient but quick and easy compromise.  (The visitor pattern would be very efficient.)

Comment: @Aragorn300 Okay, I am terribly sorry, I thought about it a bit more, (after my answer was upvoted and accepted,) and I came up with a much better solution which only involves searching for the first occurrence and then collecting only the duplicates.

Comment: Now that makes sense! Thanks for making the adjustment. I was able to get that code working. If I could upvote you twice I would. @MikeNakis

Comment: C-:= glad to be of help.  The issue was bugging me while I was brushing my teeth, so I had to return to answer it before going to sleep.